# $n$ is natural number. What is the result of $(-1)^{2n}-(-1)^{4n-1}-1^{n+1}-(-2)^3$

Tags: exponential-function, natural-numbers

$n$ is natural number.

What is the result of $(-1)^{2n}-(-1)^{4n-1}-1^{n+1}-(-2)^3$

**My attempt:**

We know that $2n$ means even, and $4n -1$ means an odd number.

Here we get

$$+1 -1 +1+8 = 9$$

Sorry If I was truly wrong, just wanted to show something I did.

Comment: It looks just fine. +1

Comment: Oh, I'm really too happy to hear this! I doubt if my solution was correct because I thought I've gone too wrong.

Comment: Yet, as you can see, it is really tricky...

Comment: @DonAntonio I just realised that I didn't completely misread, the order is wrong! Since the OP seemed to understand the even/odd part I focused on the last two.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier If the OP meant to write the figures then: the order is wrong. Yet perhaps he didn't mean that. Is for that to answer and, apparently, the same Michael meant in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just $$1+1-1+8=9.$$

Because $$(-1)^{2n}=\left((-1)^2\right)^n=1^n=1;$$
$$-(-1)^{4n-1}=-(-1)^{-1}\cdot(-1)^{4n}=(-1)^{4n}=\left((-1)^4\right)^n=1^n=1;$$
$$-1^n=-1$$ and
$$-(-2)^3=-(-8)=8.$$

Comment: I'm not sure the OP wrote his work *in the order* the summands were written in the exercise. Anyway, the result is the same.,

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm getting help from people by showing my thinkings, not waiting for a completely solution. If I didn't show my attempt, you were right.

Comment: @DonAntonio I am ready to explain for you my work. What is your question?

Comment: I'm struggling with a problem tho.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I just remarked your result is the same as the OP's, yet you seem to have written the figures in the very order they appear in the exercise, whereas the OP *apparently* didn't write them in that order...

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Why?

Comment: @Goendo I added something. See now.